# Using arbitrary XML files that can be read at runtime

Tags: android, xml, android-preferences

This is the `Activity` where I'm using the `setContentView` method. In this app I'm using a `xml` folder in the `res` folder and put a `prefs.xml` file in that.

public class SetWallpaperActivity extends Activity {

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(android.R.xml.);
    //setContentView(R.xml.prefs.xml);
    setContentView(android.R.xml.); //   This line GENERATE ERROR...
}
```

This is my `prefs.xml` file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; >    
     <CheckBoxPreference android:key="touch" android:title="Enable Touch">/CheckBoxPreference>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="numberOfCircles" android:title="Number of Circles"></EditTextPreference> 
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: this is my prefs.xml file                                      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    
<CheckBoxPreference android:key="touch"
    android:title="Enable Touch"></CheckBoxPreference>
  <EditTextPreference android:key="numberOfCircles"
    android:title="Number of Circles"></EditTextPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the xml file you posted as a comment(which has preferences in it) your probably looking to make a settings screen from which the user can set various preferences for your app. If this is the case then you need to extend the [`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) class instead of the normal `Activity`:

```
public class SetWallpaperActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.the_name_of_the_xml_file); // R.xml.prefs.xml from your code
    }
}
```

Also have a look at the official guide regarding this on the [android developers site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html).

You can't set the content view as a xml file from the `res/xml` folder, because the `setContentView` needs the id of a layout file(in the form of `R.layout.the_layout_file`).

Comment: public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
  
 
  Preference circlePreference = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(
    "numberOfCircles");

   circlePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(numberCheckListener);
 }

Comment: Here i am using the same but error defines in this line addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs); //error: prefs cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @user1838195 Did you imported the correct `R` class? Make sure that you imported the class from your own package and **not** the `android.R` class.

Comment: but its defines the force close error while running the application

Comment: i am using the wallpaper example from the http://www.vogella.com. it defines the demo for wallpaper and that i am using.But after making a correction the force close error is generated.